# Does $B(H)$ satisfy in Heine-Borel property?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Based on  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), I know that every bounded and closed subset of a space is not compact. I really want to know that $B(H)$, the space of bounded linear operators, satisfies in Heine - Borel property. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any infinite dimensional normed space lacks Heine-Borel property, because by corollary of Riesz theorem about almost perpendicular the unit ball of infinite dimensional normed space is not compact.

Comment: what about other topologies? If $\tau$ is locally convex topology weak operator topology or strong operator topology, then we can show unit ball of B(H) is $\tau-$ compact? I can prove it like Alaoglu's theorem, but I would like to know is $\tau-$ closed and boundedness of unit ball implies compactness?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to answer your second question. On the unit ball of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ weak${}^*$ topology and weak operator topology coincide and strictly weaker than strong operator topology. Therefore by Banach-Alaoglu theorem the unit ball of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is compact in both weak operator and weak${}^*$ topology. But not in the strong operator topology. For counterexample consider sequence of operators $T_n:H\to H:x\mapsto (x,e_1)e_n$, where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an orthnormal sequence in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about them. The purpose of my question is that Heine-Borel property satisfies in B(H) or every its C*-subalgebra.

Comment: or not. I mean showing that does $\tau-$bounded and closed imply $\tau-$ compact?

Comment: This is not your original question, so I won't answer it.